# Concatenate multiple columns and sort within a row

Tags: mysql, sorting, group-by, concatenation, group-concat

I have a table that has the following fields:

```
+------------------------------+
|  id  | cart1 | cart2 | cart3 |
|------------------------------|
|  1   |  ball |  soap |  NULL |
|  2   | apple | towel | paper |
|  3   |  soap |  ball |  NULL |
| .... | ..... | ..... | ..... |
+------------------------------+
```

I want the following output:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| item1 | item2 | item3 | num_appearances |
|-----------------------------------------|
| ball  | soap  |  NULL |        2        |
| apple | towel | paper |        1        |
| ..... | ..... | ..... | ............... |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Basically, `cart1`, `cart2`, and `cart3` define a person's cart, but the order doesn't matter, and I want to count up the number of times a set of items were bought together, again with order not mattering. So `apple`, `towel`, `paper` appeared once in the sample table, and `ball` and `soap` appeared twice.

What I think I need to do is sort `item1`, `item2`, and `item3`, concatenate them, and group by that concatenated value. So `group_concat` sounds great, and I can group by `id`, or some other column that is distinct for each row. But so far I have `group_concat(item1, item2, item3 [ORDER BY WHAT])`. But how do I sort a list of columns and return that concatenated, sorted list?

Comment: I'd start by collapsing the three `cart#` columns into a single column.

Comment: @TrippKinetics - that's what I'm trying to accomplish with the `group_concat`. I unfortunately can't change the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @Strawberry's suggestion in combination with my "collapse" idea.

```
SELECT  combo, COUNT(combo) total
FROM
(
    SELECT  id, GROUP_CONCAT(item ORDER BY item) combo
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  id, item1 item
        FROM    cart_table
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  id, item2
        FROM    cart_table
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  id, item3
        FROM    cart_table
    )
)
GROUP BY combo
```

As much as I dislike nested subqueries...

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,cart_no INT NOT NULL
,item VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,qty INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
,UNIQUE(cart_no,item)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,'ball',1),
(2,1,'soap',1),
(3,2,'apple',1),
(4,2,'towel',1),
(5,2,'paper',1),
(6,3,'soap',1),
(7,3,'ball',1);

SELECT cart_no,GROUP_CONCAT(item ORDER BY item) combo FROM my_table GROUP BY cart_no;
+---------+-------------------+
| cart_no | combo             |
+---------+-------------------+
|       1 | ball,soap         |
|       2 | apple,paper,towel |
|       3 | ball,soap         |
+---------+-------------------+

SELECT combo, COUNT(0) total FROM
(
SELECT cart_no,GROUP_CONCAT(item ORDER BY item) combo FROM my_table GROUP BY cart_no
) x
GROUP BY combo;
+-------------------+-------+
| combo             | total |
+-------------------+-------+
| apple,paper,towel |     1 |
| ball,soap         |     2 |
+-------------------+-------+
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I want, though, because here we have a column called `item` associated with a `cart_no`, whereas in my table, each row contains all of the items in the cart (`item1`, `item2`, `item3`). For reasons I can't explain, I know that the cart will not be larger than 3 items, so I store the data this way.